# sql store procedure being called by multiple processes

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Using: MySql server.

I'm in a situation where I need to check if a customerId exists before registering the user in a batch application.

The problem is that different thread/process of the same batch application can be trying to check if the same user is registered or not, and will try to create it if it does not exist.

After reading up I understand that a store procedure (createCustomer) which will do a select to check if the customerId does not already exists and then calls insert to register customer would be the right way. But what if 10 batch processes try calling the createCustomer store procedure with the same customerId at the same time ? what will happen in this case ? is it possible that the same user will be created 10 times here ?

Comment: If i understand it well, setting the CustomerID coloumn value UNIQUE in the database should solve this problem, so it will be created only once.

Comment: I believe that such problems should be dealt with on a database level with constraints and (if necessary) triggers.

Comment: the customerId column is already UNIQUE. But if the first batch job successful adds the customer record the other batch jobs might get duplicate record exception

Comment: @Plaha - So, do you still have a question?

Comment: @PM 77-1 ... Yes, i think insert tigger should do the job. Thanks. I don't know how to accept your answer here.

Comment: @Plaha - You are very welcome. You can't accept anything posted as comments and that's OK.